# Strange interaction of set hidden, shortmess and the status line

Tags: buffers, options, statusline

My `.vimrc` contains

```
set hidden
set shortmess=fotx
```

I start Vim 7.3 with

```
vim a b
```

I modify `a` (optional), then I save it and switch to the next file with `:wn`. Then I use `:prev` to return to the previous file. I modify the file some more (optional) and again run `:wn`.

The first time I ran `:wn`, I switched instantly to the next buffer, thanks to `shortmess=o`. But the second time, I had a two-line prompt and needed to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
"a" 1854 lines, 56709 characters written
"b" 1854 lines --0%-- (2 of 2)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

There's something going on that I don't understand with the `hidden` option. When I start Vim, the status line shows

```
"a" 1854 lines, 56709 characters                              1,1           Top
```

I get a similar line after switching to `b`. But after switching back to `a` with `:prev`, the status line is different:

```
"a" 1854 lines --0%-- (1 of 2)                                1,1           Top
```

If I remove the `hidden` option, I never see the `--0%--` form of the status line, and the `shortmess=o` option has the desired effect of not requiring a confirmation after `:wn`. But I do want `set hidden`, because I want to be able to switch buffers without saving.

Why is `set hidden` changing the format of the status line? More importantly, why is it causing me to have to acknowledge a `:wn` by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the second time, in spite of `set shortmess=fotx` still being on? How do I get the benefits of both `hidden` and `shortmess=o`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `O` to `shortmess` seems to fix this:

```
set hidden
set shortmess=fotxO
```

From `:help shortmess`:

```
o     overwrite message for writing a file with subsequent message
      for reading a file (useful for ":wn" or when 'autowrite' on)
O     message for reading a file overwrites any previous message.
      Also for quickfix message (e.g., ":cn").
```

So `o` only takes effect when *writing* a file, and `O` takes effect when *reading* a file.

Unless I've missed something, this seems to behave as you expect? I do get a different statusline, but I believe this is because the statusline is different when you open a new buffer vs. showing a previously hidden buffer...

PS. I don't have a machine with Vim 7.3, but I tested this with Vim 7.4-633, 7.4-160, and 7.2-411, using a vimrc file with only the `hidden` and `shortmess` lines.

Comment: Hmmm. It works, but I don't understand how the documentation relates to the behavior — the description of `o` even explicitly states that it applies to `:wn`. What kind of messages might `O` overwrite? I don't care about the message that a file has been successfully written, but don't want to miss important messages, like failing to write a file.

Comment: @Gilles Hm, I'm also slightly confused now ... I need to do some more digging and see how exactly this works ... stay tuned ...